# I changed my localhost Apache port . when I want to see my site it , shows me IIS

Tags: php, web, xampp, localhost

IIS or internet information service[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you visit http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it before. It's showing me IIS

Comment: XAMPP is telling you it's trying to start on port 8080, but it's already in use. Kill IIS to free up the port and restart XAMPP.

Comment: Thanks but not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. If I use HTTPS, it works. Thanks for your helps.